# Port forwarding, DMZ, turning off firewall and adding port doesn't work to reach out port

Tags: asp.net-mvc, port, portforwarding, iis-10, windows-firewall

I am using Windows 10 with IIS 10.0

I am publishing website on IIS and I need to reach it with public ip.

What I did;
 * Port forwarding through router 
 * Adding DMZ with my local IP
 * Turning off firewall
 * Adding port to firewall inbound rules with allow edge traversal

I can connect with internal IP like 192.168.1.75:81

I get "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond from [MYPUBLICIP]" when I try to reach it like MYPUBLICIP:81

What are the possible scenarios that blocks to port?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the error message means there is no server listening at specified ip/port that you are trying to connect to.

In my opinion, you should firstly make sure your client machine could access your server by using this  MYPUBLICIP address.

Then I suggest you could try to make sure the port 81 is your IIS web application port.

Besides, I suggest you could try to open your event viewer to find out the details error message.

Comment: Interestinling didn't work. I reinstalled Windows, Visual Studio 19 and SQL Server.